# Android Studio: I can not run/debug my project after cloning it from my repository

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

My HD died two days ago, luckily my android app is versioned on Bitbucket. So I got an SSD, reinstalled Windows 10 and the latest Android Studio. With Android Studio installed, I've cloned the project of my app through the 'Checkout project from Version Control' option in the welcome window of Android Studio. The project seems to have been cloned correctly, bringing all my source codes.

However, Android Studio was not able to create a Run / Debug configuration automatically. So, I tried to create a configuration by my own by clicking Edit Configurations> Add New Configuration (green cross) and choosing the option Android App. When choosing this option, the error 'Error: Module not specified' is showing below in the window, like Shows the image I attached.
[image]

This is the first time I have to clone my Android project from my repository and unfortunately I am not sure how to handle it. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the `settings.gradle` file. Create a new one in the project root folder with the following content:

```
include ':app'
include ':BaseGameUtils'
include ':squarecamera'
include ':volley'
```

I just guessed your modules, fix them in case they are not correct.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks !